# How to decrypt blocks encrypted with RSA?

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I'm still on my RSA project, and now I can successfully create the keys, and encrypt a string with them

```
def encrypt(clear_message, public_key):
    
    clear_list = convert_into_unicode (clear_message)
    
    n = public_key[0]
    e = public_key[1]

    message_chiffre = str()
    
    for i, value in enumerate (clear_list) :
        encrypted_value = str( pow (int(value), e, n) )

        encrypted_message += (encrypted_value )

    return encrypted_message 

def convert_into_unicode (clear_message):

    str_unicode = ''
    
    for car in clear_message:
        str_unicode += str (ord (car))
        
    if len (str_unicode ) % 5 != 0: 
        str_unicode += (5 - len (str_unicode ) % 5) * '0'
    
    clear_list = []
    
    i = 5
    
    while i <= len (str_unicode ):
        
        clear_list .append (str_unicode [i-5:i])

        i += 5
        
    return liste_claire
```

For example, encrypting the message `'Hello World'` returns `['72101', '10810', '81113', '28711', '11141', '08100', '32330']` as `clear_list` then
`'3863   111   1616   3015   1202   341   4096'` as `encrypted_message`

The `encrypt ()` function uses the other function to convert the string into a list of the Unicode values but put in blocks because I've read that otherwise, it would be easy to find the clear message only with frequency analysis.

Is it really that easy?

And as it probably is, I come to my main question. As you know, the Unicode values of a character are either double-digits or triple-digits. Before the encryption, the Unicode values are separated into blocks of 5 digits ('stack' -> '115 116 97 99 107' -> '11511 69799 10700')

But the problem is when I want to decrypt this, how do I know where I have to separate that string so that one number represents one character?

I mean, the former Unicode value could be either 11 or 115 (I know it couldn't really be 11, but that's only as an example). So to decrypt and then get back the character, the problem is, I don't know how much digits I have to take.

I had thought of adding a `0` when the Unicode value is < 100, but

1. Then it's easy to do the same thing as before with the frequency analysis
2. Still, when I encrypt it, '087' can result in '467' and '089' can result in '046', so the problem is still here.

Comment: Please don't encrypt arbitrarily long data with RSA. RSA is only able to encrypt long data in chunks, but RSA is not [meant](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14/13022) to be used as a block cipher. Instead, the data is encrypted with AES with a freshly generated key. The key is in turn encrypted with RSA, because it is short. This so-called [Hybrid Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) is faster and more secure (if you use an randomized and [authenticated block cipher mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Authenticated_encryption)).

Comment: Unicode codepoint numbers can be more than 3 characters long.

Comment: Please see my comment on @Marteen Bodewes' answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to solve real world problems with a toy RSA problem. The frequency analysis can be performed because no random padding of the plaintext message has been used. Random padding is required to make RSA secure.

For this kind of problem it is enough to directly use the Unicode code point (an integer value) per character as input to RSA. RSA can however only directly encrypt values in the range [0..N) where N is the modulus. If you input a larger value x then value will first be converted into the value x modulus N. In that case you loose information and decryption will not be deterministic anymore.

As for the ciphertext, just make this the string representation of the integer values separated by spaces and split them to read them in. This will take more space, but RSA always has a certain overhead.

---

If you want to implement secure RSA then please read into PKCS#1 standard and beware of time attacks etc. And, as Wyzard already indicated, please use hybrid cryptography (using a symmetric encryption in addition to RSA).

Or use a standard library, now you understand how RSA works in principle.

Comment: There can't be any problem with the range [0;N[, N has at least 4 digits and Unicode values don't exceed 3 digits (with the symbols I'm going to use). As I had said it's not a professional project, but the aim remains using RSA (not a library). Soo.. I think I must try as you both said with hybrid cryptography,

Comment: Yeah, but your `convertIntoUnicode` uses 5 digits it seems and tries to combine unicode values, which you probably should not do.

Answer (score 2):

Your `convert_into_unicode` function isn't really converting anything "into" Unicode.  Assuming `clear_message` is a Unicode string (The default string type in Python 3, or `u''` in Python 2), it's (naturally) Unicode already, and you're using an awkward way of turning it into a sequence of bytes that you can encrypt.  If `clear_message` is a byte string (the default in Python 2, or `b''` in Python 3), all the characters fit in a byte already, so the whole process is unnecessary.

It's true that Unicode string needs to be encoded as a byte sequence before you can encrypt it.  The normal way to do that is with an encoding such as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).  You can do that by calling `clear_message.encode('utf-8')`.  After decrypting, you can turn the decrypted byte string back into a Unicode string with `decrypted_bytes.decode('utf-8')`.

You don't need the `convert_into_unicode` function at all.

Comment: utf-8 doesn't like accents, and utf-8 returns a weird thing where the only change is adding '\x00' between each letter, is that normal  ?

Comment: "Doesn't like" accents?  It should handle them just fine.  Note that they'll encode into multiple bytes in the output; normal unaccented English letters encode into a single byte.  Putting "\x00" between each letter is something UTF-16 would do, not UTF-8.

Comment: Doesn't like,because it put a lot of characters for only one accent, but maybe it's normal. And you're right, the second 'utf-8' is utf-16

Comment: Yes, that's normal.  UTF-8 uses multiple bytes to represent a character whose codepoint number is greater than 127.  Depending on how big the codepoint number is, it may encode into two, three, or four bytes.  (Larger codepoint numbers generally correspond to uncommon characters, though – you'll mostly see one or two bytes per character.)

Comment: Okay, thanks. Anyway, I need to write my function all over again, so I'll mind what you said